# Unable to load nib file: MainMenu, exiting

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, xcode8, swift-package-manager

I can't figure out how to get package management working for Xcode 8, Swift 3 for a macOS Cocoa app. No matter what I do, I get:

> Unable to load nib file: MainMenu, exiting

Steps to reproduce:

1. create a new project
2. initialize Package.swift

   ```
   swift package init
   ```
3. Generate SPM file structure

   ```
   swift package generate-xcodeproj
   ```
4. Run

To troubleshoot, I've tried changing the scheme so the executable is the projectname.app, cleaning, building, force quit and reopen Xcode, adding my Developer ID and enabling signing. So far, nothing has worked.

Comment: You aren't doing 1) with Xcode, right? If you are, don't. If you're using `generate-xcodeproj`, the first step should be to just cd in an empty folder. Part 3 will create the Xcode files.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was creating the project with Xcode. Thanks! Just doing steps 2-4 and I run with no errors, though I don't have the AppDelegate and .xib file that I'm used to seeing.

Comment: Glad to see I was right about this. I've made an answer with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is because your are creating a project with Xcode in step #1.

It conflicts with the files that will be created by the Swift Package Manager (SPM).

You should just cd in a folder then do `swift package init` then `swift package generate-xcodeproj`.

This last part will generate the right project files compatible with SPM.

Note that you can use one of the existing templates to create the project files: `swift package init --type executable` or `swift package init --type library`, it will create a set of files specific to each usage.